# Support for 4oD and 5oD on openelec

Tags: openelec, pi-2

I have a raspberry pi b+ running OpenELEC (gotham) and was wondering if a new openelec os had been released that is able to fully utilise the quad core processor in the raspberry pi 2. And if there are programs released now that support 4oD and 5oD on the most current version of OpenELEC? Because I cannot find apps that can access channel 4 and channel 5 content on OpenELEC in the same way that BBC Iplayer can access BBC content. Although there are 4oD and 5oD apps that work on older versions of OpenELEC, they do not work on gotham, I have tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two distinct questions here.  In response to the first one, there isn't anything special that needs to be done to exploit multiple cores that isn't already generally done.  Multi-threaded applications run on single core machines with multi-tasking operating systems for exactly the same reason you can have more than one application running at the same time on a single core machine.  Short story: They get time sliced, these slices are measured in the low milliseconds.

If you then run the same multi-threaded application on a multi-core machine, it runs exactly the same way except better, because it doesn't get time sliced to the same extent.  This is true of all modern operating systems and applications; you don't install a special version of whatever OS depending on whether your x86_64 machine  (i.e., contemporary Intel and AMD processors) has 2 cores or 8 cores or 1 core -- it is exactly the same software.

There is something significant to consider about the Pi 2, however, and that is that it has a bit more advanced architecture than the previous models (which has nothing much to do with the number of cores).  While it will run userland code compiled for those older versions (ARMv6), if you want to get the most out of it, you should use stuff that was compiled specifically for this more advanced processor (ARMv7).  Looking at [openELEC's download page](http://openelec.tv/get-openelec), it appears they *do* have versions specifically for the Pi 2.